# C# - How to POST form data to a PHP file and permanently redirect the user to the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-post

I have an `ASP.NET CORE` checkout page, `razor page`, which contains an `HTML Form`. The payment process will be completed by a php file `pay.php`. I want to POST the Form Data, from backend (in `C#`) to a url that reaches a php file `pay.php` for processing.

So far I have code that POST form data but I want to redirect the user to the url. The processing will be handled by the pay.php and the result of the process *success or process fail* willbe rendered from the `pay.php`.

How do I achieve that? or what would you recommend is the best approach to POST from `C#` to `PHP` and then redirect the user to the url, if possible, permanet redirect?

The pay.php file will be on the same server with the `ASP.NET CORE APP`.

Here is the code I use to **POST** from `C#` to `PHP`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(FormDataModel model)
{
                string URL = "https://websitename.com/checkout/pay.php";

                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
                    formData["firstName"] = "John";
                    formData["lastName"] = "Doe";
                    formData["email"] = "johndoe@email.com";

                    webClient.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri(URL), "POST", formData);
                }
}
```

Now I am not sure how to redirect the user to the url (**https://websitename.com/checkout/pay.php**) so that they see the posted values. I hope to resolve this by your help.

Comment: If you already have a form, can't you just set the form action to be the URL to the PHP file? Then PHP will get the data while the user gets redirected. I don't see any reason for it to go through C# if all it does is posting to that file (and since you also want the user to be redirected)

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson: What you said made me laugh at myself. When I tested first with a php file in the same folder, model binding directed the POST back to the server. You just made me realise that inputting a url will POST to the file. Much appreciated and a thought that never crossed my mind.